# instantiate custom UICollectionViewCell with didHighlightItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am using `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. In order to instantiate my cell in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, I use this line:

```
let music_Cell:MusicCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("music_Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MusicCollectionViewCell
```

In this way, I am able to call upon my custom music cell and then I can manipulate it based on the status of that song (like if its playing already, etc).

For example, I can manipulate the cell like this:

```
music_Cell.song_Title_Label.text = song_Title!
```

At the end of the function I just return music_Cell. Everything works fine.... UNTIL

It seems to me that I don't have the ability to instantiate my custom cell with the function `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` and the `unHighlight` function because those function don't allow you to return a custom `UICollectioViewCell`. I want to be able to do custom UI changes when the person highlights. Thus far, the only thing I have been able to do is instantiate a regular cell, and NOT my custom one:

```
let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = opus_Page_Primary_Color
```

But I want to be able to control the other UI elements, not just the background color.

How can I do this? I have looked everywhere?

Comment: Try to get the original cell of the collection view with the indexPath. In UITableView something like self.tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(...). For sure there is an equivalent for collection views.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see your last code. I am on mobile. Just add "as MyCustomCellClass" after that row.

Comment: @KevinLieser you are right. All i had to do was replace UICollectionViewCell with the name of my custom class (MusicCollectionViewCell) and add "as! MusicCollectionViewCell".

Answer (score 0):

You handle the selection and highlighted appearance in your custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass.

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("selected") // Do your custom selection state here.
        }
    }

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("highlighted") // Do you custom highlighting here.
        }
    }
}
```

You can also take advantage of the `selectedBackgroundView` property. Setting it to a custom view will animate that view in above the cell's background view when the cell is selected:

```
public var selectedBackgroundView: UIView?
```

Note: The only time you should be dequeuing reusable cells is in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` (which is why those other delegate methods do not return a `UICollectionViewCell`).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

All I had to do was replace `UICollectionViewCell` with the name of my custom `CollectionViewCell` class.

```
let cell: MusicCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MusicCollectionViewCell!
```

Now I can access all of the elements of my custom class like so:

```
cell.song_Title_Label.text = "Song Name"
```